# What Does This Picture Say?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

I stumbled across a picture of Severus whilst on the internet, and me being who I am, this has its disadvantages.  I am not a good reader of cursive whatsoever, so if someone could help me out, that would be great. Here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: It says squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle squiggle

Comment: Well, it's in French for starters.

Comment: As I said above. I wouldn't of even known.

Comment: Bigger version here; http://th03.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/f/2009/356/4/e/Severus_Snape_Background___2_by_rouquinamour.jpg

Comment: I've taken the liberty of re-asking over on French:SE. Once we get a translation, we can locate the source; http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/what-does-this-say-in-english

Comment: I twittered [to the picture's author](http://coverjunction.com/cover/Harry-Potter-Severus-Snape) (some singer). Low chance of reply, but what the hell. It was worth creating a twitter account

Comment: Update: there's now an answer posted at the French:SE that looks good.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about science fiction and fantasy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to TrishLing's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/77044/20774), and with a major hat tip to Jilliagre over at [French:SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/12722/6418) for the wording, the translation would be something like:

> ***I am touched by what you tell me about this. You know that my heart
> beats for all of you and I know that you feel the same way.***
>
> *All of a
> sudden, good Denise doesn't want to accept the cross of our Mexican
> order. I sent him on the pretext that the Queen did not like these orders and
> it was explained to him that I had not included these orders in the first
> distribution.*
>
> *I [also] told him that Grandmother....*

Obviously the first part is actually quite sweet whereas the second half is merely a conversation about matters of family business, and appears to be there simply as filler.

Answer (score 13):

I've taken the liberty of reposting the answer posted at the [French:SE](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/what-does-this-say-in-english).

> The text reads:*
>
> > Je suis bien touchée de ce que vous me dites à ce sujet. Vous savez que mon coeur a toujours battu pour vous tous et je sais bien que c'est réciproque. La bonne Denise ne veut tout d'un coup pas accepter la croix de notre ordre mexicain que je lui ai envoyée sous prétexte que la Reine n'aimait pas les ordres et que c'était ce qui lui avait expliqué que je ne l'eusse pas comprise sous la première distribution. Je lui ai répondu que Grand' maman
>
> It is a letter written in 1866 from Charlotte, the Empress of Mexico, to her uncle, the Duke of Nemours.
>
> Source: Rice University http://scholarship.rice.edu/jsp/xml/1911/27238/1/aa00207.tei.html
>
> I wouldn't qualify this as "normal" modern writing in France but I guess most of the doctors prescriptions I had in my life were less legible than that letter ;-)

It's actually page 3 of the letter and actually starts and stops midsentence.